# Airbnb scraping con nokogiri

Tags: ruby

Estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto y necesito obtener información de la pagina de Airbnb‎ (específicamente esta url "https://www.airbnb.cl/s/Santiago--Chile?s_tag=EXop_G3D" ).
El problema sucede en la segunda línea de código:

```
url = "https://www.airbnb.cl/s/Santiago--Chile?s_tag=EXop_G3D"
html = open(url)
```

Me devuelve :

```
OpenURI::HTTPError: 503 Service Unavailable
```

Con otros sitios no obtengo este error, así que no entiendo por que este me devuelve eso.

Answer (score 1):

Esto es por que efectivamente la url sobre la que quieres hacer scrapping responde con el error 503

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Probablemente esto se deba a que este request es de tipo POST y no GET que es lo que hace la linea

```
html = open(url)
```